# Method http has died unexpectedly! Problem installing sublime text 3.0

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text

I am trying to install Sublime Text 3.0 on Ubuntu 16.0 (via crouton). I follow the instructions but I can't get `sudo apt-get update` to work. I get the following error:

```
Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received a segmentation fault.
```

If I remove the file which is created on `etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` the problem disappears and I can get `sudo apt-get update` to run with no problems. But I can't install the new version of ST!

Any ideas?

This issue is, I think, linked to the following: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/2688

Comment: A segfault is a bug, report it on your distribution's forums.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue in the following way: edited the "s" from "https" in the relevant file contained in the sources list. And was able to run sudo apt-get update as usual.

Answer (score -1):

Run this as root to fix it.

```
apt-get --reinstall install libcurl3-gnutls
```

Comment: `apt-get --reinstall` would also fail with the same error.